# How do you set the PATH in your .profile file?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

I'm currently trying out Homebrew and it has told me to list it's folder before the default installation path in the .profile.

After some googling it appears that I have to make this file myself as it is not generated. But I have no idea what a file like this looks like and I struggle finding any examples through the normal channels i.e Google.

Could you guys be of assistance?

Comment: Simply add `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` (if you want it for other shells as well).

Comment: You edit /etc/paths to have "/usr/local/bin" on top to have Homebrew's packages be prioritised.

Answer (score 0):

On OS X there are several locations where you can define `$PATH`. One is `~/.bash_profile` (Terminal.app starts the shell as a login shell on OS X, so it has to be `.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc`). This affects only `bash`. The other is `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` which can be edited either with the plist editor (if you have XCode installed) or the `defaults` command. This affects all GUI applications.

However, according to [this article](http://overwatering.org/blog/2012/08/setting-path-osx-mountain-lion/) `environment.plist` doesn't work in Mountain Lion anymore and you have to add a line `setenv PATH /bin:/usr/bin:...` to `/etc/launchd.conf` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Found this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/local/lib

alias sl='ls'
alias pwd='echo -n `pwd` | pbcopy'
```

From
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509587/unix-making-change-to-profile-file

Comment: This doesn't work since Homebrew isn't installed in `/opt`. Furthermore, only the first line would be necessary. The three others are irrelevant to the question and setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not encouraged. Also, the OP wanted to have Homebrew folders *before* other PATH directories, not after.